# Getting image from clipboard - black when screenshots appear?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, gdi

I am using WPF to display the image in the clipboard. This works fine when going to Paint and copying something there, but when I hit "Print screen" to take a screenshot, the output there is just a black image, that has the same dimensions as the screen.

How come?

The code for taking data from the clipboard is as follows (yes, I do in fact want to use raw API calls).

```
...
case CF_BITMAP:
    BitmapSource source = null;
    System.Drawing.Bitmap finalBitmap = null;
    IntPtr destinationHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    if (destinationHdc != null)
    {
        IntPtr sourceHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        if (sourceHdc != null)
        {
            if (OpenClipboard(MainWindow.Handle))
            {
                IntPtr sourceBitmap = GetClipboardData((uint)clipboardFormat);
                SelectObject(sourceHdc, sourceBitmap);

                BITMAP bmp;
                GetObject(sourceBitmap, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BITMAP)), out bmp);

                IntPtr destinationBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(destinationHdc, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight);
                SelectObject(destinationHdc, destinationBitmap);

                BitBlt(destinationHdc, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, sourceHdc, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
                CloseClipboard();

                finalBitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromHbitmap(destinationBitmap);
            }
            DeleteDC(sourceHdc);
        }
        DeleteDC(destinationHdc);
    }
    if (finalBitmap != null && ((LastData == null || !(LastData is System.Drawing.Bitmap)) || !finalBitmap.EqualsTo((System.Drawing.Bitmap)LastData)))
    {
        source = BitmapToSource(finalBitmap);

        if (LastData == null || source != LastData)
        {
            tile = new ImageTile();
            (tile as ImageTile).Image.Source = source;
            tile.RawData = finalBitmap;
        }
    }
    return tile;
...
```

Comment: I seriously doubt anybody is going to volunteer to debug this code for you, especially since you omitted the pinvoke declarations.  It is silly to not use the Clipboard.GetImage() method here.

Comment: The Clipboard.GetImage function is buggy, which has in fact been confirmed, even for .NET 4.0. It will crash for some types of images (for instance images coming off a word document).

Comment: First I heard of it.  Although it inevitably depends on the quality of the code that put the image on the clipboard.  What's wrong with try/catch?

Comment: We're talking about a FatalException, that will crash even the try/catch. It'll seriously shut down the application with NO chance of recovering. It's honestly that critical.

Comment: I think you're better off uninstalling the program that screws up the clipboard like this.  Stops it from crashing .NET programs whose code you don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the inbuilt framework method instead, Clipboard.GetImage(). The WPF version of it seems to work better than the Windows Forms one.